Dynamic TabView frame height
I'm facing an issue with my TabView. Essentially I get data from my backend that is displayed to the user. That data is displayed in a custom view that contains expandable elements (the user can click on an element and additional details are displayed).
The issue I've been facing is making sure the TabView has the correct height to display the elements. I've been able to dynamically increase the height using geometry reader (using a reduce function), but not to dynamically set it (meaning the height only increases but never decreases, resulting in a largely empty space if the user collapses the details again).
I'm wondering if I am even using the right fundamental approach here. The code is as follows:

struct MyCustomView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyCustomViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewModel.profileImages.isEmpty {
                Text("No images available.")
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else {
                TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedIndex) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.profileImages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        SinglePhotoView(viewModel: viewModel, index: index)
                            .tag(index)
                    }
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                .frame(height: viewModel.tabViewHeight)
                .animation(.easeInOut)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SinglePhotoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: MyCustomViewModel
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if index < viewModel.profileImages.count {
                Image(uiImage: viewModel.profileImages[index])
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 300, maxHeight: 300)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .shadow(radius: 5)
                    .padding()
            }
            
            if index < viewModel.optimizerResults.data.photos.count {
                let photo = viewModel.optimizerResults.data.photos[index]
                let recommendation = photo.recommendation
                let detailedRecommendation = viewModel.optimizerResults.data.photosDetailed[index]
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Overall score")
                        .font(.title)
                    if detailedRecommendation.overallAssessment.overallScore > 10 {
                        ProgressBarColored()
                    } else {
                        ProgressBarColored()
                    }
                    if recommendation.keep == 0 {
                        Text("Replace this image")
                    }
                    
                    
                    if viewModel.showDetails1 {
                        VStack {
                            SingleProgressResult(<some attributes>)
                            SingleProgressResult(<some attributes>)
                            SingleProgressResult(<some attributes>)
                            SingleProgressResult(<some attributes>)
                        }.padding()
                    }
                    Divider()                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .layoutPriority(1)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: geometry.size.height)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { height in
            print("height: \(height)")
            viewModel.tabViewHeight = height
        }
        .id(viewModel.showPersonalityDetails)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}


I ended up solving this using a hack. I measure each VStack in SinglePhotoView and use a separate ViewHeightKey for each. I track those values in my ViewModel and have a function to simply sum them all to give me the total height. Every time one of the VStack changes, it triggers a new calculation and the TabView frame height is adapted. I’d still be curious if there is a better way.
